# another equivalent expectation form

Tags: probability, expectation

I am reading *Networks, Crowds, and Markets Reasoning about a Highly Connected World*. section 8 of Chapter 28. I am confused about the another equivalent expectation. I never see that before. Does any can help me? Thanks for your time.

> To recap the discussion there, the definition for the expected value is
>   $$ E[X_n] = 1 × Pr[X_n = 1] + 2 × Pr[X_n = 2] + 3 × Pr[X_n = 3]+· · · (21.3) $$
>   and an alternate but equivalent way to write the right-hand side is
>   $$Pr[X_n ≥ 1] + Pr[X_n ≥ 2] + Pr[X_n ≥ 3]+· · · , (21.4)$$
>   since we observe that each term $Pr[X_n = i]$ contributes exactly i copies of itself to the
>   sum in (21.4). Therefore, we have
>   $$E[X_n] = Pr[X_n ≥ 1] + Pr[X_n ≥ 2] + Pr[X_n ≥ 3]+· · · . (21.5)$$

It seems probability distribution is:

$X_n$`|    1            2            3       .`

P  `|`  $Pr[X_n = 1]$  $Pr[X_n = 2]$  $Pr[X_n = 3]$

but why

> $$Pr[X_n ≥ 1] + Pr[X_n ≥ 2] + Pr[X_n ≥ 3]+· · · , (21.4)$$

Should I give more information about this? Thanks for your consideration.

**EDIT**

> **The Expected Number of Infected Individuals.** We start by considering an approach
>   to this problem that gets us partway to a proof of the claim: considering the expected number of infected individuals at each level of the tree.
>      First, let’s consider the total number of individuals at each level. The number of individuals at any given level exceeds the number at the previous level by a factor of $k$, and therefore the number who are at level n is $k_n$. (This is also true at level $n = 0$; the top level consists of just the root, and $k_0 = 1$.) 
>   Now, let $X_n$ be a random variable equal to the number of infected individuals at
>   level n. One way to think about the expected value $E[X_n]$ to write $X_n$ as a sum of simpler random variables as follows. For each individual $j$ at level $n$, let $Y_{nj}$ be a random variable equal to $1$ if $j$ is infected, and equal to $0$ otherwise. Then
>   $$X_n = Y_{n1} + Y_{n2} +· · ·+Y_{nm},$$
>   where $m = k_n$, since the right-hand side simply counts, one by one, the number of infected individuals at level n. Linearity of expectation says that the expectation of the sum of a set of random variables is equal to the sum of their expectations,
>   and so
>   $$E[X_n] = E [Y_{n1} + Y_{n2} +· · ·+Y_{nm}] = E[Y_{n1}] + E[Y_{n2}]+· · ·+E[Y_{nm}] . (21.1)$$
>   The reason to write things this way is that each expectation on the right-hand
>   side is extremely easy to work out: $E[Y_{nj}] = 1 × Pr[Y_{nj} = 1] + 0 × Pr[Y_{nj} = 0]= Pr[Y_n = 1]$, and so the expectation of each $Y_{nj }$ is just the probability that individual $j$ gets infected.
>
> Individual $j$ at depth $n$ gets infected precisely when all of the $n$ contacts leading from the root to $j$ successfully transmit the disease, as shown in Figure 21.14. Since each contact transmits the disease independently with probability $p$, individual $j$ is infected with probability $p_n$. Therefore, $E[Y_{nj}] = p_n$.We have already concluded that there are $k_n$ individuals at level $n$ of the tree, and hence $k_n $ terms on the right-hand side of Equation (21.1). Therefore, as summed up in Figure 21.15, we conclude that
>   $$E[X_n] = p^n k^n = (pk)^n = R^n_0. (21.2)$$
>   **From Expected Values to Probabilities of Persistence.** Equation (21.2) suggests the importance of the basic reproductive number $R_0$ in reasoning about the spread of an epidemic in the branching process model. Now let’s consider what this tells us about $q^∗$, the probability that the epidemic persists indefinitely.
>   First, the fact that $E[X_n] = R^n_0$ immediately establishes part (a) the claim we are trying to prove, that when $R_0 < 1$ we have $q^∗ = 0$. To see why, we go back to the definition of $E[X_n]$ and apply a fact that we also found useful in Section 20.7.
>
> To recap the discussion there, the definition for the expected value is
>   $$ E[X_n] = 1 × Pr[X_n = 1] + 2 × Pr[X_n = 2] + 3 × Pr[X_n = 3]+· · · (21.3) $$
>   and an alternate but equivalent way to write the right-hand side is
>   $$Pr[X_n ≥ 1] + Pr[X_n ≥ 2] + Pr[X_n ≥ 3]+· · · , (21.4)$$
>   since we observe that each term $Pr[X_n = i]$ contributes exactly i copies of itself to the
>   sum in (21.4). Therefore, we have
>   $$E[X_n] = Pr[X_n ≥ 1] + Pr[X_n ≥ 2] + Pr[X_n ≥ 3]+· · · . (21.5)$$
>
> From Equation (21.5) we observe that $E[X_n]$ must be at least as large as the first term on the right-hand side, and so $E[X_n] ≥ Pr[X_n ≥ 1]$. Notice also that $Pr[X_n ≥ 1]$ is precisely the definition of $q_n$, and so $E[X_n] ≥ q_n$. But $E[X_n] = R^n_0$, which is converging to $0$ as $n$ grows; hence, $q_n$ must also be converging to $0$. This shows that $q^∗ = 0$ when $R_0 < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p(X\geq1)=p(X=1)+p(X=2)+p(X=3)+...+p(X=n)$$
$$p(X\geq2)=p(X=2)+p(X=3)+...p(X=n)$$

Keep writing these out and add them all up, and the result follows